# Protractor-cucumber Allure report not showing full test results

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs, allure

Iam Running Protractor-cucumber tests and generating allure reports ,report is getting generated but for some reason report is not displaying full test results, i have followed all the instructions as mentioned in 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumberjs-allure-reporter' below is the xml file generated

```
<ns2:test-suite xmlns:ns2="urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru" start="1490864784836" stop="1490864784933">
    <name>1</name>
    <title>1</title>
    <test-cases>
        <test-case start="1490864784839" stop="1490864784931" status="passed">
            <name>Login and Enter Customer Details</name>
            <title>Login and Enter Customer Details</title>
            <description></description>
            <labels>
            </labels>
            <parameters>
            </parameters>
            <steps>
                <step start="1490864784840" stop="1490864784847" status="passed">
                    <name>I navigate to &quot;http://test.index.html;</name>
                    <title>I navigate to &quot;http://test.index.html;</title>
                    <attachments>
                    </attachments>
                    <steps>
                    </steps>
                </step>
                <step start="1490864784848" stop="1490864784865" status="passed">
                    <name>I login as test</name>
                    <title>I login as test</title>
                    <attachments>
                    </attachments>
                    <steps>
                    </steps>
                </step>
                <step start="1490864784865" stop="1490864784866" status="passed">
                    <name>check whether login is successful</name>
                    <title>check whether login is successful</title>
                    <attachments>
                    </attachments>
                    <steps>
                    </steps>
                </step>
                <step start="1490864784866" stop="1490864784868" status="passed">
                    <name>the protractor api should be available</name>
                    <title>the protractor api should be available</title>
                    <attachments>
                    </attachments>
                    <steps>
                    </steps>
                </step>
```

and below is the reporter.js

```
var reporter = require('cucumberjs-allure-reporter');
reporter.config(
    {
        targetDir:'./allure-results/'
    }
);
module.exports = reporter;
```

Below is the cucumber-allure installation details
npm WARN Calms3@1.0.0 requires a peer of cucumber@>= 1.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN cucumberjs-allure-reporter@1.0.3 requires a peer of cucumber@>= 1.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-protractor-runner@3.2.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN Calms3@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN Calms3@1.0.0 No license field.

can somebody please help on this..

Below is the conf.js

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'features/sample.feature'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--start-maximized'
      ]
    }
  },

  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/*.js',
    format: 'pretty'
  },
};
```

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Calms3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor framework for Cucumber.js",
  "main": "Conf.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webdriver": "webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=2.53.1 && webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=2.53.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "test",
    "testing",
    "webdriver",
    "webdriverjs",
    "selenium",
    "protractor",
    "protractor-framework",
    "cucumber",
    "cucumber-js",
    "gherkin",
    "bdd"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "cucumber": ">= 1.3.0 || >= 2.0.0-rc.0",
    "protractor": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "6.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.17.1",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "httpster": "1.0.3",
    "multidep": "2.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "jasmine-allure-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.3.0",
    "winston": "2.3.1",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.3.3",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "protractor-helpers": "1.1.0",
    "cucumberjs-allure-reporter": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "cucumberConf": {
    "version1": "1.3.1",
    "version2": "2.0.0-rc.8"
  }
}
```

report doesn't show anything on steps executed..

Comment: Can you mention your conf.js settings and what is the expected result?

Comment: Ram, i have added the conf.js file content in original post

Comment: Allure reporter should generate an xml file, which it consumes to display the results in jenkins, Can you check if the steps are displayed in that xml file or not? if not then something wrong with allure reporter also share me your package.json file

Comment: I have added the package.json and xml generated is pasted on the top, i have also mentioned WARN messages displayed when it Allure npm package is intalled.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I see from your package.json, you are using cucumber peerDependency 1.3.0 or 2.0 rc, You see allure reporter currently doesn't support cucumber version > 2.0. So you have to use cucumber 1.3.0 only to generate allure reports successfully.

As of now please remove the cucumber 2.0 dependency and use only 1.3.0, you would be able see your reports.

I am sure in future allure-reporter would support latest cucumber versions(2.0)

Comment: Tried  but still the same, when i check for 'npm cucumber --version' it is showing as 4.1.2 , guess it is protractor-cucumber version, please suggest me further on this.

Comment: Please install cucumber 1.3.0 and protractor as dependencies and not as peer-dependencies, your package.json should look like this - [package.json](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-allure/blob/master/package.json), Notice the dependencies protractor & cucumber

Comment: It is still the same , iam not sure what iam missing ,i will share my project hierarchy and different components.